# Global gitignore of files with tilde "~" (at the end of file name)

Tags: linux, git

My operating system is: Linux Fedora 19

On Linux when I edit a file, some text editors create a backup of that file. And git sees that backup file as a new file: `my_file.txt~`

How can I make a global gitignore of files with tilde `~` (at the end of file name) without creating the `.gitignore` file?

Comment: What's wrong with a .gitignore file?

Comment: it works only for one directory

Comment: You want it for all of your git repos?

Comment: yes, because i don't need these backup files at non of my git repos

Comment: @MichaelVayvala `git config --global ...`  See `help git config`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure a global gitignore file which will affect all of your local repos:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

Then treat it just as the usual per repo .gitignore file.

See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files for more options.

Comment: it still show me that: 
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
# my_file.txt~

Comment: Works perfect for me, just tried it. Never used it before either.

Comment: Probably because that file was already tracked before you added the line to `.gitignore` (Read the page that Troy linked.)

Comment: this: """ echo "*~" > ~/.gitignore_global """ fixed my problem